# install conky, configure:error:required header(s) not found

Tags: software-installation, conky, configure

I am trying to install:http://sourceforge.net/projects/conky/files/conky/
But when I do ./configure I get: configure:error:required header(s) not found.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try  Conky 1.9.0 deb from this ppa.

https://launchpad.net/~vincent-c/+archive/conky/+packages

Comment: I got the same error with that too.